# Tensorflow ImageDataGenerator for CNN returns "TypeError: Cannot interpret 'tf.float32' as a data type" when looking at data

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am trying to make a CNN and everything was fine until I got to model.fit(...) when I got the TypeError in the title that I haven't seen before. I cast the dtype as a tf.float32 in my ImageDataGenerator. The flow_from_directory seems to work just fine and has the correct amount of images between the validation and training datasets so I am not sure what is happening.

My Code is below excluding the imports and random variables that are just ints or the filepaths for the folders.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

img_height, img_width = 224

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    data_format='channels_last',
    validation_split=0.1,
    dtype=tf.float32,
)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    filepath,
    target_size = (img_height,img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size
)


nonsense = train_generator[0][0] #<===Error is happening here
print(nonsense.dtype)`
```

I was expecting this to work without issue. But, I don't know if there is something underlying I am missing I am using tensorflow 2.10.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the default `dtype` is already `tf.float32`, so no need to change it. But it you want to specify it explicitly, use the string format, like this:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    validation_split=0.1,
    dtype='float32'
)
```

Here is a fully reproducible example:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    validation_split=0.1,
    dtype='float32'
)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'path/to/my/dataset',
    target_size=(32, 32),
    batch_size=16
)

inputs, labels = next(iter(train_generator))
```